# How to display listitems of ul always when opened

Tags: html, css, cordova

We are working on a web app with Cordova using HTML and CSS in the pages.

For dropdowns we are using ul elements.

Now we have the following problem.

When a page is higher than the screen and we do vertically scroll so that one of the dropdowns is at the displayed end of the visible area and we open the list, the list is not displayed in the visible area, but vertically under the ul element.

Here an example for such an ul element on one of our pages:

```
<div class="CellOuter"
     style="top: 650px; left: 115px;">
    <div class="CellInner TopLeft"
         style="height: 20px; width: 45px; ">
        <ul id="10001"
            name="myDropDown"
            class="DropDownMenu TopLeft"
            style="font-size: 10px; max-height: 20px; width: 45px;"
            required=""
            tabindex="24">
                <div class="Selection">
                </div>
                <li class="DropDownItem" value="0" sortorder="0" style="display: none;"></li>
                <li class="DropDownItem" value="1001" sortorder="1" inilang="false" textkey="DropDownList_1" style="display: none;">yes</li>
                <li class="DropDownItem" value="1002" sortorder="2" inilang="false" textkey="DropDownList_2" style="display: none;">no</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a possibility with CSS to change the ul elements in such a kind, that the listelements are always displayed in the visible area when the list is opened?

Thanks in advance!

Patrick

Comment: please show  us your code

Comment: please create a code snippet of your code. thanks

Comment: I have added an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't know what you want, but if you need to set width or height base on screen by css, you can try `height: 100vh` `or width: 80vh`.

Comment: The problem is that when th ul is at the end of the visible area and the list opened, the items are displayed below in the not visible area. Just when we scroll down we can see the opened list.

Comment: i cant test your problem but plz try to close the <div class="Selection"> before </div> </ul>

Comment: No, there is no way to handle this in CSS alone. You could add JavaScript that checks where the element is currently located, whether it is closer to the top or bottom of the browser window, and then reacts to that in some way … Question would be, which way - if you automatically scroll the document further down, then you will lose the mouse position, and if the dropdown was opened on hover only, it might collapse again … Other alternative could be to have the dropdown items open above the trigger element in such a case, instead of below.

Comment: Thank You 04FS for the hint. I will try that.